# tgamma() long long typecasting

Tags: c++, numbers, c++14, factorial

I am writing a function in which I have to calculate factorial of numbers and do operations on them.The return value of the function should be long long so I think it would be better to do all operations in long long format. If I am wrong please correct me.

The tgamma() function by itself returns the correct value in scientific notation. But the the value returned by tgamma() is sometimes 1 less than actual answer when the value returned by the function is typecasted to 'long long'.

```
 int main()
{
std::cout<<"11!:"<<tgamma(12)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"12!"<<tgamma(13)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"13!"<<tgamma(14)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"14!"<<tgamma(15)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"15!"<<tgamma(16)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"16!"<<tgamma(17)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"********************************"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"11!:"<<(long long)tgamma(12)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"12!"<<(long long)tgamma(13)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"13!"<<(long long)tgamma(14)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"14!"<<(long long)tgamma(15)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"15!"<<(long long)tgamma(16)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"16!"<<(long long)tgamma(17)<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
 11!:3.99168e+07
 12!4.79002e+08
 13!6.22702e+09
 14!8.71783e+10
 15!1.30767e+12
 16!2.09228e+13
 ********************************
 11!:39916800
 12!479001599
 13!6227020799
 14!87178291199
 15!1307674367999
 16!20922789888000
```

The actual value of 15! according to [this site](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/factorials.php) is 1307674368000 but when I typecast tgamma(16) to long long, I get only 1307674367999. The thing is this discrepancy only appears for some numbers. The typecasted answer for 16! is correct - 20922789888000.

This function is for a competitive programming problem which is currently going on, so I can't paste the function and the solution I am developing to it here.

I would roll my own factorial function but I want to reduce the number of characters in my program to get bonus points.

Any tips on how to detect this discrepancy in typecasted value and correct it? Or maybe some other function that I can use?

Comment: tgamma works with floating-point numbers, which may lose precision. Why don't you just write your own factorial function using integers?

Comment: "The tgamma() function by itself returns the correct value in scientific notation. " - No, it doesn't. C++ has a clean design. The value is returned as a binary value. Scientific notation is a text format which can applied when converting a binary value to text.

Answer (score 0):

Casting from a floating point type to an integral type truncates.  Try `(long long) roundl(tgammal(xxx))` to get rid of integer truncation error.  This is also using long doubles so it may give you more digits.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout<<"11!:"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(12))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"12!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(13))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"13!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(14))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"14!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(15))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"15!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(16))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"16!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(17))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"********************************"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"11!:"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(12))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"12!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(13))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"13!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(14))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"14!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(15))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"15!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(16))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"16!"<<(long long)roundl(tgammal(17))<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
11!:39916800
12!479001600
13!6227020800
14!87178291200
15!1307674368000
16!20922789888000
********************************
11!:39916800
12!479001600
13!6227020800
14!87178291200
15!1307674368000
16!20922789888000
```

Comment: Why does this error only appear for some numbers though? Shouldn't it be uniform if it is an error? Why only 15! typecasted answer is erroneous while 16! answer is not?

Comment: tgamma is approximate. Casting to an integral type truncates instead of rounds. Using more digits and round/roundl will help with both.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, unless we have very unusual implementation, not all long long numbers can be exactly represented as double.  Therefore, tgamma cannot store double values such that casting to long long would produce exact value.  Simply there are more long long values than double values within long long interval.

If you want exact long long factorial, you should implement it yourself.

On top of this, if you want precision, you transform double to long long not as (long long)x, but as (long long)round(x), or (long long)(x+0.5), assuming x is positive.

Comment: nice explanation! The (long long)(tgamma(x) + 0.5) produces shorter code...nice tip!

Comment: is there any standard c++ function that returns the exact factorial of a number without having to do such typecasting error workarounds?

Comment: Google for `std factorial standard library` and you'll find the answer :)